# php include error Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to put my `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` in other page, but it shows error and doesn't work. before I moved the code from the `check_login.php` to `header.php` the code works fine
this is my `header.php`

```
<?
$domain = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '170693';
$con=mysql_connect($domain,$username,$password);
 if(!$con)
 {
 die(mysql_error());
 }
mysql_select_db("sure") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

and this is the `check_login.php`

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();

 include("header.php");
 $user=$_POST['username'];
 $pass=$_POST['password'];
 ....
```

Comment: This won't fix your error, but ext/mysql is deprecated. Consider switchting to ext/PDO or ext/mysqli. Apart from that: **Related** Section to the right. [Please do research before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access+denied+for+user+%27ODBC%27%40%27localhost%27+%28using+password%3A+NO%29+).

Comment: the link you said is the same problem with me is different. In my case, it work fine for the connection when I put the header.php inside the check_login.php, but when I seperated and use the include, it doesn't work

Comment: I asked you to look at the related section and do research, not to just look at the question I closed yours with. There is at least two questions with the same title in the Related section and there is 55 search results linked in my comment and [google has 168k results](https://www.google.de/search?q=Access+denied+for+user+'ODBC'%40'localhost'+(using+password%3A+NO)) as well. Try to understand the error message.